# Create a Flash Fonts from different sources

Tags: flash, actionscript, fonts

In Actionscript/Flash it is possible to create a swf which contains font data for emedding like this:

```
package {
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  public class Font_times_new_roman extends Sprite {
  [Embed(
    systemFont='times new roman',
    mimeType='application/x-font',
    fontName='times new roman',
    fontWeight='normal',
    fontStyle='regular',
    unicodeRange='U+0020-U+007E,U+00A0-U+00AC,U+00AE-U+00FF,U+0100-U+017F,U+037E-U+037E,U+0384-U+038A,U+038C-U+038C,U+038E-U+03A1,U+03A3-U+03CE,U+0400-U+045F,U+20AC-U+20AC')]
  public static var FontClass:Class;
  }
}
```

now what i would like is, to create something like this with glyphs from different source fonts.

for example unicode character x should be taken from Arial, while character y should be from times new roman.

is that possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

I cover the different ways you can embed fonts on my site (it's long, so it's easier to link): http://divillysausages.com/blog/as3_font_embedding_masterclass

Basically, if you just want a swf that's nothing but fonts, then you embed the ones you need (changing the `systemFont`, or embedding the same font but changing the `fontWeight` if you want a font that has normal and bold for example), the export the swf. If you just want to embed a specific glyph, then set the unicode value directly in the `unicodeRange` parameter.

An easier way would be to do it through Flash - create a textfield with each font/glyph that you want, then use that in your main swf (explained how in the link). It's much easier than working with unicode, especially if you only want one glyph.

What you're trying to do - embed a font for a different character - is possible, but it's awkward, and I'm not sure you're going to be able to get the effect that you want without a lot of hassle. The normal method of using a `TextFormat` ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html ) object with your `TextField` won't really work as you can only apply one at a time.

You can use HTML text, and the `StyleSheet` class ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html - for each style, point the `fontFamily` to the font you've embedded), but it'll result in a lot of markup (you'll need to span each letter with a different style).

Possible, but kind of awkward.

Comment: thanks. not sure if this might work. what i want to do is the following: i have a font which is missing all the greek characters. now since they look quite different from all the other characters, i might as well integrate them from another font.

Comment: In that case you either need to embed a font that has proper support for the characters you're looking for, or use something like arial (and possibly not embed it if you don't need to). TweetDeck does something like this - their normal font is latin characters only. If you want the full alphabet, you need to turn off embedded fonts